# Calling Bot (Teams, Skype, etc...)

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm planning to create a calling bot (a bot that someone or group can call using MS Teams, Skype, etc...)
is there a sample or a guide on how to develop the above?
I've followed the [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/tutorial-voice-enable-your-bot-speech-sdk)
and added the bot to Teams, however whenever I call it I get a reply that "you can't talk to this bot just yet but we are working on it"

Comment: have you looked at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot? this is for MS teams

Comment: I did, when calling the bot from teams I get  "you can't talk to this bot just yet but we are working on it"